# How can I shortcuts request session in Django Python?

Tags: python, django, templates

Here's my views.py code:

```
def checkout(request):
    request.session["quantity"] = int(request.POST["quantity"])
    request.session["price"] = float(request.POST["price"])
    quantity_from_form = request.session["quantity"]
    price_from_form = request.session["price"]
    total_charge = quantity_from_form * price_from_form


    context = {
        'quantity_from_form': quantity_from_form,
        'price_from_form': price_from_form,
        'total_charge': total_charge
    }

    print("Charging credit card...")
    Order.objects.create(quantity_ordered=quantity_from_form,
                         total_price=total_charge)
    return render(request, "store/checkout.html", context)
```

I want to shortcuts naming request.session[" "]  = request.POST[" "]. Is there any way i can shortcut this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
for key in ("quantity", "price"):
    request.session[key] = request.POST[key]
```

BUT 1/ it wont convert your values to the desired type and 2/ you should NOT use unvalidated, unsanitized user inputs anyway, so the proper solution is to use a Django `Form` (or ModelForm if the point is to create a new model instance).

Also, you should only create a model instance in a POST request - GET requests **MUST** (not "should" - "must") be idempotent.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help. I will fix my problem